# JFM Template does not work with BibTex file?

Tags: bibtex

I have a problem with a journal template class, it stops compiling when I include a bibtex file for the references.

I am using the JFM [template](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/information/instructions-contributors).

If I comment out the bibliography include command, the pdf is compiled with ??? instead of references.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{jfm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf, epsfig}

\shorttitle{T-Junction}
\shortauthor{E.}
\title{T-Junction}
\author{Edgar}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
Authors should not enter keywords on the manuscript, as these must be 
chosen by the author during the online submission process and will then 
be added during the typesetting process (see 
http://journals.cambridge.org/data/\linebreak[3]relatedlink/jfm-\linebreak[3]keywords.pdf for the full list)
\end{keywords}


\section{Introduction}
Model on shortened thesis introductions
\begin{itemize}
\item Wide range of applications of capsules and inherent interest
\item Scarcity of experimental studies
\item Importance of understand how capsules negotiating bifurcations
\item Applications to measure deformability and sort capsule by deformability
\item introduce the four papers \cite{KoolivandDimitrakopoulos2017, KuriakoseDimitrakopoulos13} \cite{KuriakoseDimitrakopoulos11, HuEtAl12} that have dealt with a T-Junction, and rectangular and square channels
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{jfm}
\bibliography{Capsules}
\end{document}
```

If I don't use the JFM style, everything compiles without a hitch

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\title{T-Junction}
\author{Edgar}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Model on shortened thesis introductions
\begin{itemize}
\item Wide range of applications of capsules and inherent interest
\item Scarcity of experimental studies
\item Importance of understand how capsules negotiating bifurcations
\item Applications to measure deformability and sort capsule by deformability
\item introduce the four papers \cite{KoolivandDimitrakopoulos2017, KuriakoseDimitrakopoulos13} \cite{KuriakoseDimitrakopoulos11, HuEtAl12} that have dealt with a T-Junction, and rectangular and square channels
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{plain}    % (uses file "plain.bst") %nar
\bibliography{Capsules}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure how to proceed with debugging this. Any help appriciated.

**Update 15/01/2018**
The problem occurs on Windows with MixTex, default Latex enviroment on Mac OSX and Ubuntu.

Not sure how what causes it, sometimes it works and then stops working. No error messages, the latex/pdflatex never completes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you're getting `????` instead of usable citation call-outs, the likely culprit is that you didn't run BibTeX successfully, followed by two more (pdf)LaTeX runs.

Comment: The JFM class uses the `natbib` package. As said in the [instruction PDF document](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/5a0c2cef1faa2add64df8263/JFM%20IFCs%2015_11_2017.pdf) page 7, you have to use either `\citep{}̀` (citation between parentheses) or `\citet{}` (citation in the text) commands, instead of native `\cite{}` command.

Don't forget to compile several times : Pdflatex, Bibtex, Pdflatex and Pdflatex again.

Comment: @Tobard that turned out to be the main problem! When using JFM style, no errors are shown for some reason, so I found it very difficult to debug. If you submit this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @EdgarH, OK, this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JFM class uses the `natbib` package. As said in the [instruction PDF document](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/5a0c2cef1faa2add64df8263/JFM%20IFCs%2015_11_2017.pdf) page 7, you have to use either `\citep{}̀` (citation between parentheses) or `\citet{}` (citation in the text) commands, instead of native `\cite{}` command.

Don't forget to compile several times : Pdflatex, Bibtex, Pdflatex and Pdflatex again.